# First assembly program

Tags: assembly

I'm doing x86 assembly in `debug.exe` for my course, however I seem to completely fail to understand the basics. I have this assembly program (written by the lecturer) and I have to modify it so instead of taking an input and printing it would take an input do something with it and then print. I have no idea where does the read end and print begin and would really appreciate some tips on where to insert my code and what does each line do

```
a100
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 0a
int 21
mov bh, 00
mov bl, byte ptr[201]
mov byte ptr[200], 0d
mov byte ptr[201], 0a
mov byte ptr[202 + bx], 24
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 09
int 21
mov ah, 4c
int 21

a200
db 07 00 '***********'

n progr1.com
r cx
100
w
q
```

Comment: http://static.patater.com/gbaguy/x86asm.htm

Comment: Here you go: [Interrupt 21h reference](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would perhaps start reading about each of those lines one at a time and just see what they do.

For example, as someone in the comments said, Read about what `int 21` does, it does many things, depending on what is in the `AH` register.

http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm

e.g.
Reading a line from STDIN is specified by `0A` in the `AH` register, it places the output in the DX register in a certain format.

```
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 0a
int 21
```

Number of characters read is placed in the second byte of DX, and so it is saved into BX using these lines:

```
mov bh, 00
mov bl, byte ptr[201]
```

Printing to the screen is done with a different `INT 21` `AH` value, `09`, and it is read from whereever `DX` points to, which is why DX is set back to `200`

```
mov dx, 200
mov ah, 09
int 21
```

I will leave it to you to figure out what the rest does, but have a look at the format of reading in and writing out here http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm. For instance this line `mov byte ptr[202 + bx], 24` is placing an ASCII 0x24 in the last position in the string, because that is the terminating character for reading.

Comment: Thank you, that was a big help. I have done my program, it works but i dont understand why it still works after deleting 

a200
db 07 00 '***********'